# About Android Frameworks, UI design, and tips

Tags: java, android, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

Is there some native android framework that uses only java? Example: create buttons, text fields, containers, ext.

And my biggest problem is with the design. I would like to know if is there any framework that facilitates apply styles to buttons, fields, layers, etc? Like twitter bootstrap, but only in java. I do not want html and css frameworks .. I used the phonegap and is very slow compared to native app.

I should use Framework or create my own code?

Comment: What is a "native android framework that uses only java?" Android already has a `Button` class, an `EditText` class, various classes implement containers, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using the native Android framework using Java to write your code and XML to write your layouts.

The first reason you will want to do this is *speed* (like you said yourself, native apps typically run much smoother than apps created using PhoneGap and other third-party frameworks).

The second reason is that there is a ton of documentation and tips online teaching you how to write Android apps... there won't be nearly as much documentation available to you if you decide to auto-generate your application using some sort of third-party framework.

To help generate layouts, there is a GUI-builder that you can use in both Android Studio and Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I developed an application using native code and other application using phonegap .. I prefer the native code, it is much faster.;) I'll read more android documentation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK available from developer.android.com is the preferred framework. It is based on Java. Apps are written in Java, using the Android API. You must use the Android widgets, not the Java Swing widgets. You can apply styles to Android widgets.

When you go into a new development environment/platform, regardless of what it is, you can only take your existing knowledge so far. Designing web apps and web GUIs is not exactly the same as designing Android apps and GUIs. Designing an Android app is not even the same as designing an iOS app, although many developers make that mistake.

You may be able to craft a simple, functional app using a development tool such as twitter bootstrap (in the past, these were known as "fourth-generation languages" to differentiate them from regular programming languages such as PL/1, Pascal, etc.). At some point, however, you won't be able to get exactly what you're looking for, and then you'll have to learn how to use the SDK as delivered.

In short, none of the shortcuts get you there exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know a bit of java for android. I'll start studying more the android documentation. Thank you ;)